# MySQL Accepts update with ANDs in SET clause

Tags: mysql

I can't explain to my students why MySQL doesn't return an error for this

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1 = 2 AND col2 = 'Fred' AND col3 = 5 WHERE id = 6;
```

I know what the correct query is, and I know what goes wrong with this query, but why does MySQL allow this query?

Comment: What does the value of `col1` become? I'm guessing either 1 or 0 because the whole thing gets misinterpreted as a logical operation and returns the result of that as a boolean to the first column listed.

Comment: the query is correct  the use of logical operator is allowed  .. (no sense in this case)..but allowed

Comment: AND is a logical operator in this case, you are only going to update col1 with the value of 2 AND (t/f) AND (t/f) depending on the values of col2 being fred and col3 being 5

Comment: Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feb8df/1

Comment: This must be equivalent to `UPDATE table1 SET col1 = (2 AND col2 = 'Fred' AND col3 = 5) WHERE id = 6` which is valid SQL syntax.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos is correct in that case col1 become 0 if the where clause is satisfied

Comment: Can you hear the penny dropping? Thanks everyone. Well done to Michael for the speedy addition to sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Pete, I am so glad this question is still here almost four years later... we just ran into this and this was enlightening.